# The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have created a angular asp.net core web app with identity. The app was executing fine but after taking latest code from azure devops I am unable to execute the project.
Error on executing the app:
TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
I have tried following:

1. npm install on clientapp folder
2. Delete node_modules and run above command
3. Uninstalled node.js, restarted my laptop and reinstalled node.js
4. Repaired visual studio

Below is the error I get after executing the code,

[image]

And the package.json file,

[image]

[image]

I am using VS 2019 with angular asp.net core 3.1 identity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling `@angular-devkit/build-angular`
then install it again